# Tensorflow: ValueError: `generator` yielded an element of shape () where an element of shape () was expected

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network

My dataset:

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
     data_generator.generate,
     output_types=({"input_1": tf.int64, "input_2": tf.int64}, tf.int64), 
     output_shapes = ({"input_1": tf.TensorShape([None, 500]), "input_2": 
                     tf.TensorShape([None, 500])},tf.TensorShape(None)))
```

My preprocess function returns:

```
return ({'input_1': ids1, 'input_2':  ids2}, label)
```

My model (taking multiple inputs):

```
input_1 = Input(shape=(500,) , name='input_1')
............
input_2 = Input(shape=(500,) , name='input_2')
```

On starting the training, I'm getting the following error:
`ValueError: generator yielded an element of shape (500,) where an element of shape (None, 500) was expected`

Any idea what I might be doing wrong ?

EDIT: On updating the output_shapes to:

```
output_shapes = ({"input_1": tf.TensorShape([500]), "input_2": tf.TensorShape([500])},tf.TensorShape(None)))
```

I get the following warning:
`WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 500) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 500), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1'), name='input_1', description="created by layer 'input_1'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (500, 1)`